# How to structure a graph convolution model in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

So the idea is I want to be able to predict properties of an entire graph based on its adjacency matrix and features for each node.

Right now for training I consider my training data as a giant sparse `N x k` matrix where each of the `N` nodes (`N` nodes across every graph in the training data) has `k` features.

I can perform the graph convolutions just fine, and I end up with an `N x l` matrix where there are `l` features for each node.

The challenging part is handling the graph readout, that is- to output a static vector for each *graph* rather than each *node*. My training labels are per graph. I need to split up my `N x l` tensor into `c` many `n_i x l` tensors where there are `c` different graphs, and graph `i` has `n_i` many nodes.

I attempted to use `tf.dynamic_partition` to accompslish this (since its easy to know which nodes correspond to which graph) but it requires a static number for the number of partitions (in order to be differentiable?), BUT this number obviously depends on the number of graphs that I want to train/validate/test on. Therefore it can't be static.

I'm kind of stuck on how to structure this now. It's not a typical use of tensorflow from my understanding because I perform computation on each node, then I need to sum up all the values from each particular graph so I can get the final outputs to be per graph rather than per node.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated